# Spring Boot: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to set home page of my application by using spring boot.. but I am getting the error as **Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**

My code is as follow

RunApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RunApplication {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RunNavneetApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RunNavneetApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/productImages/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:/home/rahul/Desktop/product_images/")
        .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wocs</groupId>
  <artifactId>REST</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
<java-version>1.8</java-version>
<service-version>0.1.36-SNAPSHOT</service-version>
</properties>  

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.wocs</groupId>
          <artifactId>services</artifactId>
          <version>${service-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.. Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 8):

Removing of @EnableWebMvc annotation works for me in Spring Boot Project.

Answer (score 5):

For me (spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.5.RELEASE) it worked changing the path in this way:

`src/main/resources/`<del>WEB-INF</del>`/view/index.html` →
`src/main/resources/`**META-INF/resources**`/view/index.html` (for some reason it seemed not liking the `WEB-INF` name and it needed the nested `resources` directory).

It seems to work also with `src/main/`**resources/resources**`/view/index.html`

In these cases you don't even need to add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and implement the `WebMvcConfigurer` (prefix and suffix configured in `application.properties` are enough).

I add to my answer also a clarification about the MVC configuration taken from the Spring Boot Reference Guide:

> **27.1.1 Spring MVC Auto-configuration**
>
> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add additional MVC configuration [...] you can add your own `@Configuration` class of type `WebMvcConfigurer` but **without** `@EnableWebMvc`.
>
> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own `@Configuration` annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`.
>
> **76.7 Switch off the Default MVC Configuration**
>
> The easiest way to take complete control over MVC configuration is to provide your own `@Configuration` with the `@EnableWebMvc`
> annotation. Doing so leaves all MVC configuration in your hands.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when doing a CURL request in my spring boot application:

> {"timestamp":1566549840380,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","message":"Could not resolve view with name 'createApiKey' in
>   servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'","path":"/createApiKey"}

I fixed it by changing from @Controller to @RestController (which is a combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody) like this:

```
@RestController
public class ApiKeyController {
    ...
    @GetMapping("/createApiKey")
    public DeferredResult<CreateApiKeyResp> createApiKey(@RequestParam long userId) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing the thymeleaf dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have defined suffix and prefix

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

So all page in your request will convert to html file automatically,so you need to change `return "index.html";` to `return "index";`

Change to

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: I tried but error is same... I have edited the question... please check

Comment: Request mapping should be with @Controller anotation like

Answer (score 0):

Circular view path changes for spring-boot application getting jsp pages

```
Changes required in application.properties

spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Changes in pom.xml

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```